# jquery get query string from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to read a query string from a url and alert a message based on the query string. The strings are being passed on perfectly, I am just haveing trouble reading them on the page. what am i doing wrong?

possible query strings

```
.../playlist.html?vid=1
.../playlist.html?vid=2
```

js

```
$(function () {
if (window.locaion.search.indexOf('vid=1') > -1) {
        alert('1');
} else if (window.locaion.search.indexOf('vid=2') > -1) {
        alert('2');
}
});
```

Comment: locaion is a typo right?

Comment: You've written 'locaion' instead of 'location'. Is that typo in your running code, or just in the question here?

Comment: typo?  try location instead of what you had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems: you mistyped location, and you need to toString() it, because location isn't a string. So the corrected version:

```
$(function () {
    if (window.location.toString().indexOf('vid=1') > -1) {
        alert('1');
    } else if (window.location.toString().indexOf('vid=2') > -1) {
        alert('2');
    }
});
```

Comment: ... I tried just correcting the location typo and it still wouldn't work for me. Changing .search to .toString() did - but maybe the .search is a jQuery thing, which I don't have loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Change `window.locaion` to `window.location`